# Copy to kill-ring selected file names/full path

Tags: dired

windows 10, emacs 25.1, dired+

Suppose in folder I select 3 files. 
Something like this:

[image: dired_select]

Now I want 2 options:

1. Copy to **kill-ring** the selected files names.
   So the result must be:

   ic_contact_us_write_us.png

   ic_in_store_green.png

   ic_m_brands_active.png
2. Copy to **kill-ring** the full path of selected files names.

So the result must be:

```
d:/TEMP/1/drawable-hdpi/ic_contact_us_write_us.png

d:/TEMP/1/drawable-hdpi/ic_in_store_green.png

d:/TEMP/1/drawable-hdpi/ic_m_brands_active.png
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can copy file names by pressing `w`. It calls the function `dired-copy-filename-as-kill`:

> (dired-copy-filename-as-kill &optional ARG)
>
> Copy names of marked (or next ARG) files into the kill ring. The names
>   are separated by a space. With a zero prefix arg, use the absolute
>   file name of each marked file.

Hence, in order to copy the full path of marked files to the kill ring, I've added the following piece of code:

```
(defun tl/dired-copy-path-at-point ()
    (interactive)
    (dired-copy-filename-as-kill 0))

(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "W") 'tl/dired-copy-path-at-point)
```

Comment: Also a universal argument works: C-u 0 M-x w (I just learned)

Comment: This answer should be updated.  The interactive command `dired-copy-filename-as-kill` is correct, but the advice should really be to use the universal argument directly rather than defining another command.  Simply use `C-u 0 w` (@RecencyEffect's comment probably contains a typo).

Comment: Why use `C-u 0 w` when `C-0 w` is simpler?

Comment: This answer (killing a file) doesn't fully answer the question (killing the currently selected files which could be multiple files.)